# How to keep validation over this cart button?

Tags: android, validation

Kindly check this link , in this on click of cart button ,it shows animation that its added to cart , but i want to keep a validation over this button ,then only it should get added to the cart . Please help me with this code

https://github.com/truizlop/FABRevealLayout

Answer (score 1):

You've got two possibilities:

1) Override the clickListener from the library by registering your own at the FloatingActionButton using *fabButton.setOnClickListener(myListener)*. Make sure you're doing that after the fabRevealLayout has been inflated and initialized. In *onCreate()* after calling through to *super.onCreate()* should be fine.
Inside your own clickListener, you perform your validation and based on the result manually trigger the revealing of what the library considers the "secondary view" (*fabRevealLayout.revealSecondaryView();*) or do not.

2) Register a onTouch listener to the fab button. Inside that touch-listener you check whether it is an ACTION_DOWN event and then do your validation. If it succeeds, return true to notify the system, that the event has not been handled by your functionality (that it has "consumed" the event). Downside: No click sound when pressing among others, so "not the nice way", as we're interfering the android touch handling. On the other hand you do not have to manipulate the third party library.

I would recommend going with the first option.

Comment: Not working buddy..If u have tried then can you upload an example ? i need it badly.